# String equality failure in Python. What gives?

Tags: python, string, comparison, equality

Alright, I give up. I cannot understand the result I am getting from the following code (Python 2.6.6):

```
message.dest = message.dest.strip()
print type(message.dest)
print message.dest
if message.dest == 'UI':
    print "Equal!"
else:
    print "Not Equal!"
```

Somehow my output is:

```
<type 'str'>
UI
Not Equal!
```

Any ideas on what is going on here?

Comment: Try printing `repr(message.dest)`.

Comment: would be nice if downvoters cared to explain themselves.

Comment: @Simon: see my answer, but in brief: No effort to resolve his own problem, this can only benefit OP, no-one else.

Comment: @Marcin, I have to disagree with your assessment. As edited this question serves as a valuable lesson in how to diagnose a string comparison problem. I don't see any need to reopen the question but it would be a shame if it were ever deleted.

Comment: @MarkRansom That was then, this is now. I have reopened the question.

Answer (score 6):

*Originally posted by OP in body of question. Converted to community wiki answer.*

I just wanted to follow-up with what the problem was in case anyone else finds themselves in a similar situation.

The problem was `message.dest` had an ASCII-encoded character in the string, e.g.,

```
>>> repr(message.dest)
"'\\x00UI'"
>>> print message.dest
UI
```

Personally my confusion stemmed mostly from the fact that the object type was `<type 'str'>`. This highlights the danger of using `print` statements as a debugging tool.